# Error : Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void calculateTotalAmount(List<Bill__c>, Boolean) from the type BillTriggerHandler

Tags: apex, error

This is my Bill Trigger:

```
trigger Billtrigger on Bill__c (before insert, before update, before delete, after insert, after update, after delete,after undelete) {
    
    if(Trigger.isBefore){
        
        if(Trigger.isInsert){
            
            BillTriggerHandler.calculateTotalAmount(Trigger.new,false);
        }
        if(Trigger.isUpdate){
            BillTriggerHandler.calculateTotalAmount(Trigger.new,false);
        }
        if(Trigger.isDelete){
            
        }
    }
    if(Trigger.isAfter) {
        if(Trigger.isInsert) {
            BillTriggerHandler.auditBillAmtCustomer(Trigger.newMap, null);
            
        }
        if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
            BillTriggerHandler.auditBillAmtCustomer(Trigger.newMap, Trigger.oldMap);
        }
        if(Trigger.isDelete){
            
        }
        if(Trigger.isDelete){
            
        }
        if(Trigger.isUndelete){
            
        }
    }
}
```

---

The below is my BillTriggerHandlerClass:

```
public class BillTriggerHandler {
    
    public static void calculateTotalAmount(List<Bill__c> billRecords){
        
        Set<Id> creditCardsIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<billRecords.size();i++){
            
            creditCardsIds.add(billRecords[i].Credit_card__c);
        }
        
        Map<Id,Credit_card__c> creditCardMap = new Map<Id,Credit_card__c>();
        List<Credit_card__c> creditCards = [SELECT Id, Transaction__c, One_Time_Cost__c,Rental_Charge__c FROM Credit_card__c where Id in :creditCardsIds];
        for(Integer i=0;i<creditCards.size();i++){
            
            creditCardMap.put(creditCards[i].Id,creditCards[i]);
        }
        
        for(Integer i=0;i<billRecords.size();i++){
            
            billRecords[i].Total_Bill__c = billRecords[i].Cash_Withdrawal__c  + creditCardMap.get(billRecords[i].Credit_card__c).One_Time_Cost__c +
                creditCardMap.get(billRecords[i].Credit_card__c).Rental_Charge__c + billRecords[i].Number_of_Transaction__c * creditCardMap.get(billRecords[i].Credit_card__c).Transaction__c;
                                                                                
                
        }
    }
    
    //Creating Audit of Bills
    public static void auditBillAmtCustomer(Map<Id,Bill__c> newBills, Map<Id,Bill__c> oldBills) {
        
        if(oldBills != null) {
            List<Audit__c> auditBills = new List<Audit__c>();
        
        //Step 1 - Collect all Bills whose total amunt got changed.
        for(Integer i=0 ; i<newBills.values().size(); i++) {
            if(newBills.values()[i].Total_Bill__c != oldBills.get(newBills.values()[i].Id).Total_Bill__c) {
                
                Audit__c auditBill = new Audit__c();
                auditBill.Custom_Customer__c = newBills.values()[i].Custom_Customer__c;
                auditBill.Old_Bill_Amount__c = oldBills.get(newBills.values()[i].Id).Total_Bill__c;
                auditBill .New_Bill_Amount__c = newBills.values()[i].Total_Bill__c;
                auditBills.add(auditBill);
            }
        }
        INSERT auditBills;
    } else {
            
            List<Audit__c> auditBills = new List<Audit__c>();
            for(Integer i=0 ; i<newBills.values().size();i++) {
                
                Audit__c auditBill = new Audit__c();
                auditBill.Custom_Customer__c = newBills.values()[i].Custom_Customer__c;
                auditBill.Old_Bill_Amount__c = 0;
                auditBill.New_Bill_Amount__c = newBills.values()[i].Total_Bill__c;
                auditBills.add(auditBill); 
            }
            INSERT auditBills;
        }
        
    }
}

>>>>>>CreditCardTrigger is below:

trigger CreditCardTrigger on Credit_card__c (before insert, before update, before delete, after insert, after update, after delete,after undelete) {

    if(Trigger.isBefore){
        
        if(Trigger.isInsert){
            
            //BillTriggerHandler.calculateTotalAmount(Trigger.new);
        }
        if(Trigger.isUpdate){
            //BillTriggerHandler.calculateTotalAmount(Trigger.new);
        }
        if(Trigger.isDelete){
            
        }
    }
    if(Trigger.isAfter) {
        if(Trigger.isInsert) {
            //BillTriggerHandler.auditBillAmtCustomer(Trigger.newMap,null);
            
        }
        if(Trigger.isUpdate) {
            CreditCardTriggerHandler.recalculateBillAmounts(Trigger.newMap, Trigger.newMap);
        }
        if(Trigger.isDelete){
            
        }
        if(Trigger.isDelete){
            
        }
        if(Trigger.isUndelete){
            
        }
    }
}

>>>>>The below is code for CreditCardHandlerClass :

public class CreditCardTriggerHandler {
    
    public static void recalculateBillAmounts(Map<Id,Credit_card__c> newCards,Map<Id,Credit_card__c> oldCards ){
        
        //colleect all credit cards whose values got changed
        Set<Id> changedCardsIds = new Set<Id>();
        for(Integer i=0;i<newCards.values().size();i++){
            
            if(newCards.values()[i].One_Time_Cost__c != oldCards.get(newCards.values()[i].Id).One_Time_Cost__c ||
               newCards.values()[i].Transaction__c != oldCards.get(newCards.values()[i].Id).Transaction__c ||
               newCards.values()[i].Rental_Charge__c != oldCards.get(newCards.values()[i].Id).Rental_Charge__c) {
                                      
                   changedCardsIds.add(newCards.values()[i].Id);                   
                   
               }
        }
        
          //Step 2 - Collect all bills against the changed Credit Cards
        List<Bill__c> billRecords = new List<Bill__c>();
        billRecords = [SELECT Id, Name, Custom_Customer__c , Credit_card__c ,Start_Date__c, End_date__c, Number_of_Transaction__c,Cash_Withdrawal__c,Total_Bill__c
                       FROM Bill__c WHERE Credit_card__c IN :changedCardsIds] ;
        
        //Step 3- Recalculation of Total Amount of Bill 
        BillTriggerHandler.calculateTotalAmount(billRecords, true);      
        
    }

}

*********Error message*********:

1. Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void calculateTotalAmount(List<Bill__c>, Boolean) from the type BillTriggerHandler

2. Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void calculateTotalAmount(List<Bill__c>, Boolean) from the type BillTriggerHandler

3. Method does not exist or incorrect signature: void calculateTotalAmount(List<Bill__c>, Boolean) from the type BillTriggerHandler
```

Comment: Did you check if thr Handler Class got saved successfully before saving the trigger. If not this might cause the above error. Can you try  saving the Handler and logging out and log in and check if it got saved successfully and then create Trigger on it

Comment: Salesforce Stack Exchange is a community knowledge base, not a paid support channel. Please understand that expressions of urgency and requests for private or hands-on assistance aren't really appropriate here. If you need immediate, hands-on help, your Salesforce support subscription (if present) or a hired consultant are the most appropriate solutions.

Comment: @RavindraSingh Please stop posting comments. Put all of the needed information _as text_ in the body of your post.

Comment: Hello @DavidReed, I have mentioned everything in the body of the email.

Comment: There is no email here, Ravindra. Your post _does not_ contain all of the errors that you previously posted in both comments and screenshots.

Answer (score 0):

The error message is related to the fact that you are invoking the `calculateTotalAmount` method while passing a list of sObjects and a Boolean value whereas the method only takes as an argument the list of sObjects (`calculateTotalAmount(List<Bill__c> billRecords`).

So you should either modify the method or invoke it from the handler class while passing only the list of sObjects.